# Xamarin Forms Picker SelectedItem to existing SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker, selecteditem

I am fairly new to this, and am having some issues trying to set a Picker SelectedItem to an existing SQLite table.

I have managed to populate the picker (and tables) with no issues. Now I need to Updated (or Insert) the existing cell value with the SelectedItem.

I can set the SelectedItem value, but when trying to insert it into an existing table I am having issues.
I did find one way to get it set, but doing so creates a new table each time (with the SelectedItem correctly displaying).

Is there something I am missing to get the SelectedItem into an existing table, without having to create a new table each time?

Thanks!

Xaml.cs

```
     void TermGoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //local database where populated table is stored
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            //sets the Picker SelectedItem index
            var pickerItem = termPicker.Items[termPicker.SelectedIndex];

            //created new Courses table
            var courses = new Courses();

            //sets the PickerItem column with the Selected Item on newly created table.
            courses.PickerItem = pickerItem;
            conn.Update(courses);

            Navigation.PushAsync(new TermPage());
        }

    }
```

Xaml

```
     <Picker x:Name="termPicker"
                ItemsSource="{Binding terms}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TermName}"
                Title="Select a term"
                IsEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: you need to retrieve the existing item from the db first, then update it's properties, then do the DB update.  If you just create a new `Courses` record every time then of course it will insert a new row in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I had tried to access the existing Courses table using

```
    var courses = conn.Table<Courses>;
```

but it wouldn't find the PickerItem column. So I had removed it. However, I added

```
    var courses = conn.Table<Courses>.FirstOrDefault();
```

And it worked perfectly!

Thanks @Jason for pointing me in the right direction!